# Node.js : get cloudant variable form app.js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ibm-cloud

I have the node js application on bluemix. I want to use the cloudant variable on app js from provider js.But it does not work. Please help me review it

app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express'),
routes = require('./routes'),
user = require('./routes/user'),
 http = require('http'),
 path = require('path'),
 fs = require('fs'),
 ibmbluemix     = require('ibmbluemix'),
 ibmpush     = require('ibmpush');



var app = express();

var db;

var cloudant;

var fileToUpload;

var dbCredentials = {
    dbName : 'my_sample_db',
    dbProvider : 'provider'

};

var config      = {
    // change to real application route assigned for your application
    applicationRoute : "http://demo.mybluemix.net"
    //for test by postman.
};

// init core sdk
ibmbluemix.initialize(config);
var ibmconfig = ibmbluemix.getConfig();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var logger = require('morgan');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/style', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/views/style')));

//CORS middleware
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key,IBM-APPLICATION-SECRET,IBM-APPLICATION-ID,IBM-DEVICE-MODEL,IBM-DEVICE-TYPE,IBM-DEVICE-ID,IBM-DEVICE-PLATFORM-VERSION, IBM-DEVICE-NAME,IBM-REQUEST-CORRELATION-ID,X-REWRITE-DOMAIN');

    next();
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(errorHandler());
}

function initDBConnection() {

    if(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES) {
        var vcapServices = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
        // Pattern match to find the first instance of a Cloudant service in
        // VCAP_SERVICES. If you know your service key, you can access the
        // service credentials directly by using the vcapServices object.
        for(var vcapService in vcapServices){
            if(vcapService.match(/cloudant/i)){
                dbCredentials.host = vcapServices[vcapService][0].credentials.host;
                dbCredentials.port = vcapServices[vcapService][0].credentials.port;
                dbCredentials.user = vcapServices[vcapService][0].credentials.username;
                dbCredentials.password = vcapServices[vcapService][0].credentials.password;
                dbCredentials.url = vcapServices[vcapService][0].credentials.url;

                cloudant = require('cloudant')(dbCredentials.url);

                // check if DB exists if not create
                cloudant.db.create(dbCredentials.dbName, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) { console.log('could not create db ', err); }
                });

                db = cloudant.use(dbCredentials.dbName);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(db==null){
            console.warn('Could not find Cloudant credentials in VCAP_SERVICES environment variable - data will be unavailable to the UI');
        }
    } else{
        console.warn('VCAP_SERVICES environment variable not set - data will be unavailable to the UI');

    }
}

initDBConnection();

app.get('/', routes.index);

function createResponseData(id, name, phone, attachments) {

    var responseData = {
        id : id,
        name : name,
        phone : phone,
        attachements : []
    };

    attachments.forEach (function(item, index) {
        var attachmentData = {
            content_type : item.type,
            key : item.key,
            url : '/api/favorites/attach?id=' + id + '&key=' + item.key
        };
        responseData.attachements.push(attachmentData);

    });
    return responseData;
}

function createResponseDataProvider(id, provider_type, name, phone, mobile, email, logo, address) {

    var responseData = {
        id : id,
        provider_type: provider_type,
        name : name,
        phone : phone,
        mobile: mobile,
        email: email,
        logo: logo,
        address : address
    };

    return responseData;
}




    //=============get api/rovider/:id================
app.use("/", require('./lib/provider'));
require('./lib/provider');
module.exports.cloudant=cloudant;
module.exports.cloudant1="demo";

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

and provider.js file

```
    var router = require('express').Router();
var cloudant= require('../app').cloudant;
var cloudant1= require('../app').cloudant1;

//create del all whitespace of string function
String.prototype.delAllWhiteSpace = function() {
    return this.split(' ').join('');
};
var Providers = {
 getProvider: function(req, res){
  console.log(cloudant);
  console.log(cloudant1);
 }
};

router.get('/abc/provider/',    Providers.getProvider);
module.exports = exports = router;
```

when calling API http://demo.mybluemix.net/abc/provider, the return results are cloudant undefined

Comment: I assume that you configured the URLs to match your environment?

Comment: @data_henrik: yes, it 'same enviroment, maybe using global cloudant variable is wrong here ?